# Automatic sitemap.xml

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

I am trying to figure out if it would be better to automate my sitemap or to manually update it monthly.

I am not very good with how sitemaps work in the first place so trying to learn about them now is something that I am really interested in doing. Would automating the sitemap make a large difference in the indexing process? Does the sitemap have anything to do with the indexing process in the first place?

Also could I go about using a system similar to this in my sitemap and have it extremely limited in the sitemap but would still crawl all of the links on that page?

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.somedomain.com/category/</loc>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

Or would I need to make it so that the entire sitemap has each post like this

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.soundpiff.com/category/example-content.html</loc>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.80</priority>
</url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you create it manually or automatically, the result should be the same, and consumers would not now about how it got created in the first place (they can’t see behind the curtain).

But in case of manually, if you only intend to update it monthly, you might loose 1 month until new pages get indexed, in the worst case (!). Worst case, because many consumers might use other ways in addition for finding new pages.

The [Sitemaps protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) doesn’t define a mechanism for specifying URL templates, so no, you should list absolute URLs of the pages you want consumers to know about. See also their FAQ [Do URLs in the Sitemap need to be completely specified?](http://www.sitemaps.org/faq.html#faq_url_format): "Yes."